# (char *) cast for skip using offsetto

Tags: c++, pointers

I am studying about secure coding.

In the second code example of the following page, there is a recommendation to use (char *) for "skip" variable.
https://www.securecoding.cert.org/confluence/display/seccode/EXP08-C.+Ensure+pointer+arithmetic+is+used+correctly

I am not quite sure about the address calculation in this example. So I made following code.

```
#include <stddef.h>
#include <iostream>
using namespace std;

// https://www.securecoding.cert.org/confluence/display/seccode/EXP08-C.+Ensure+pointer+arithmetic+is+used+correctly

struct big {
    unsigned long long ul1_1; // 8
    unsigned long long ul1_2; // 8
    unsigned long long ul1_3; // 8
    int si_4; // 4
    int si_5; // 4
};

void getAdrs(void *p) {
    cout << p << endl;
}

int main() {
    size_t skip = offsetof(struct big, ul1_2);

    struct big *s = (struct big *)malloc(sizeof(struct big));

    cout << skip << endl; // 8

    getAdrs(s               ); // 0x9a38008 
    getAdrs(s + skip        ); // 0x9a38108 (+256)
    getAdrs((char *)s + skip); // 0x9a38010 (+2)

    unsigned long long val[4];
    getAdrs(&val[0]); // 0xbfacc0f0
    getAdrs(&val[1]); // 0xbfacc0f8 (+8)
    getAdrs(&val[2]); // 0xbfacc100 (+16)

    free(s);
    s = NULL;

    return 0;
}
```

http://ideone.com/b5kmS4

It seems to me that both of the followings return incorrect address.

1) getAdrs(s + skip); // original non-compliant code

2) getAdrs((char *)s + skip); // recommendation

In this case, I think ((head address of struct big) + 0x08) should be obtained because the ul1_2 is located at the 8th byte counting from the head of the struct big. Is it right?
However, the case 2 above seems to return (head address of struct big + 0x02).

Am I correct, or my understanding about the address is incorrect?

Answer (score 5, accepted):

You are absolutely right! And so is your code! The only thing wrong is... your hexadecimal math. :)

```
getAdrs(s               ); // 0x9a38008 
getAdrs(s + skip        ); // 0x9a38108 (+256)
getAdrs((char *)s + skip); // 0x9a38010 (+2)


>>> print 0x9a38010 - 0x9a38008
8
```

(Honestly, don't feel bad. I spent five minutes staring at it and the linked docs before I saw it. I've made that mistake many times before.)

Comment: Thank you very much, Christian Ternus. So I made mistake by considering in decimal not in hexadecimal in the subtraction.

Comment: Yup, that's exactly it. Again, an easy mistake to make. You should be proud that you were confident enough in your reasoning to stick with your analysis and ask what was wrong. Happy coding :)